# Best way to pass Url to another page

Tags: php, javascript, url, redirect, internationalization

I have pass url to another page via javascript .For example `www.example.com/share.php?url=http://google.com/`  (I create whole url via javascript , I add my url variable to static string (which is `www.example.com/share.php?url=` ) and I redirect user to this page). But while I am passing url variable to share script , special characters(ğüşiöç) in url change or disappear. What should I do to Url string to keep it unchanged .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function before your url.